# initMap is not a function 4

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem when I try to show a map with all the companies of an organization in my web.

When I go to my website I see that the map is not displayed.
I'm going to inspect item and I get the error "initMap is not a function".

I do not know why this error is due.
Can you help me?

I attach the code:

```js
<?php
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='80.32.126.235'){
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}
$json = file_get_contents('https://aplicatiuspin.cat/aplicatiu/webServices/views/?v=empreses/json&idAplicatiu=59&idEtiqueta=1&template=none');

$empreses = json_decode($json, true);


?>
<div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initMap() {
        var map_cnt = {lat:41.563211, lng:2.008875};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 6,
            center: map_cnt,
            scrollwheel: false
        });
        var mapBound = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        <?php
        foreach ($empreses as $e) {
        if (is_numeric($e['latitud']) && is_numeric($e['longitud'])) {
        ?>
        var marker<? echo $e['id'];?> = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(<? echo $e['latitud'];?>, <? echo $e['longitud'];?>),
            map: map,
            title: '<? echo addslashes($e['nom']); ?>'
        });
        mapBound.extend(marker<? echo $e['id'];?>.getPosition());
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker<? echo $e['id'];?>, "click", function () {
            var tmp = jQuery("#divEmpresa<?=$e['id']; ?>");
            tmp.popup('show');
        });

        map.fitBounds(mapBound);
        <?
        }
        }
        ?>
    }
</script>
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
<script src="/webServices/views/js/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>
<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 1px;">
<?php
foreach ($empreses as $e):?>
        <div class="divEmpresa" id="divEmpresa<?=$e['id']; ?>" style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 20px; border-radius: 5px; width: 50%;">
            <div style="text-align: right; padding: 0 5px;">
                <a href="#" class="divEmpresa<?=$e['id']; ?>_close" >
                    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <!--<div class="col-sm-4"><img src="/webServices/views/img/empresa<?=$e['id']; ?>.jpg"> </div>-->
                <div class="col-sm-8"><h2><?=$e['nom']; ?></h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <?=$e['adreca']; ?><br>
                    <?=$e['cp']; ?> - <?=$e['poblacio']; ?> <br>
                    <?=$e['telefon']; ?><br>
                    <a href="<?=$e['web']; ?>" target="_blank"><?=$e['web']; ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?
endforeach;
?>
</div>
    <script>
        jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.divEmpresa').popup({
                transition: 'all 0.3s',
                scrolllock: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='80.32.126.235'){
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}
$json = file_get_contents('https://aplicatiuspin.cat/aplicatiu/webServices/views/?v=empreses/json&idAplicatiu=59&idEtiqueta=1&template=none');

$empreses = json_decode($json, true);


?>
<div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initMap() {
        var map_cnt = {lat:41.563211, lng:2.008875};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 6,
            center: map_cnt,
            scrollwheel: false
        });
        var mapBound = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        <?php
        foreach ($empreses as $e) {
        if (is_numeric($e['latitud']) && is_numeric($e['longitud'])) {
        ?>
        var marker<? echo $e['id'];?> = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(<? echo $e['latitud'];?>, <? echo $e['longitud'];?>),
            map: map,
            title: '<? echo addslashes($e['nom']); ?>'
        });
        mapBound.extend(marker<? echo $e['id'];?>.getPosition());
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker<? echo $e['id'];?>, "click", function () {
            var tmp = jQuery("#divEmpresa<?=$e['id']; ?>");
            tmp.popup('show');
        });

        map.fitBounds(mapBound);
        <?
        }
        }
        ?>
    }
</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.25&key=enter-your-key-here&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/1.7.13/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>


<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 1px;">
<?php
foreach ($empreses as $e):?>
        <div class="divEmpresa" id="divEmpresa<?=$e['id']; ?>" style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 20px; border-radius: 5px; width: 50%;">
            <div style="text-align: right; padding: 0 5px;">
                <a href="#" class="divEmpresa<?=$e['id']; ?>_close" >
                    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <!--<div class="col-sm-4"><img src="/webServices/views/img/empresa<?=$e['id']; ?>.jpg"> </div>-->
                <div class="col-sm-8"><h2><?=$e['nom']; ?></h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <?=$e['adreca']; ?><br>
                    <?=$e['cp']; ?> - <?=$e['poblacio']; ?> <br>
                    <?=$e['telefon']; ?><br>
                    <a href="<?=$e['web']; ?>" target="_blank"><?=$e['web']; ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?
endforeach;
?>
</div>
    <script>
        jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.divEmpresa').popup({
                transition: 'all 0.3s',
                scrolllock: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

You have create a google API key and paste it in 'enter-your-key-here' place.

To create google API key click below link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Cheers!!

Comment: First, thank you for answering.
I've replaced the code so you offer me with the generated key and it keeps telling me the same ...

The code stayed like this: 
<script async defer src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDmbZv0_hGVvX6Kf05zLN_RgRd1RxXqhj8&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/1.7.13/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>

Comment: Did you add version - https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.25&key=yourkey&callback=initMap

Comment: InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function

Comment: At first I put it and it gave me the same error so much of the version to try but it is not solved.

Comment: You have to add callback=initMap too. I have pasted your code in my machine its working properly.

Comment: @JaviPalacios you still have the `function initMap()` defined in your code?

Comment: I updated the full code. Please replace your code and add the google key.

Answer (score 0):

You have to forgot add `google-api-key` like below.

Get your [YOUR_API_KEY](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) here and added it..

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```